# Searching for column-indices of a multi-dimensional array that match multiple conditions (one condition per row)

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy, search

I have written a script that I believe works and covers all edge-cases. I am curious about ways to improve upon speed. While the given example below covers a multi-dimensional array of `3 rows x 10 columns`, my actual use case will be `n rows x ~70,000 columns` (where `n` depends upon the number of data parameters being searched).

Given individual arrays of data points, the goal is to combine them into a multi-dimensional array and find the columns in which all conditions are satisfied. If the same column of each row satisfies a given condition, the index that corresponds to that column is output; otherwise, an error is raised.

I have included a small `class` named `MaskOps()` because it has many other functions relevant in my main code, though I've only included the parts relevant to the goal in this question.

```
import numpy as np

class MaskOps():

    @staticmethod
    def get_base(shape, value, dtype=int):
        """ This function produces a base-mask, the values of which may be overwritten. """
        if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            res = np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype) * value
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            res = np.array([value for idx in range(np.prod(shape))]).reshape(shape)
        return res

    @staticmethod
    def alternate_base(shape, key):
        """ This function creates base-masks that consist of one of two value; the value depends on the index input as the parameter key. """
        if key % 2 == 0:
            value = 0.25
        else:
            value = 0.5
        return MaskOps().get_base(shape, value, dtype=float)

MO = MaskOps()
```

Sample Data

```
row_a = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
row_b = row_a * 10
row_c = row_a + 20
data = np.array([row_a, row_b, row_c])
```

Main Search Function

```
def core_algorithm(ndata, search_value):
    """ 
    This function prints values and indices that match the search condition. 

    An index mask of non-zero values is created per row of the input data, 
    and the values of the index mask are overwritten to be a zero at each
    column at which the condition is satisfied - per condition and row of data.
    Then, the columns of the index masks that sum to zero are the column-indices 
    that satisfy all input conditions.
    """

    print("\nSEARCH VALUES:\n{}\n".format(search_value))
    print("NDATA:\n{}\n".format(ndata))

    bases = np.array([MO.alternate_base(len(ndata.T), idx) for idx in range(len(ndata))])
    print("ORIGINAL BASES:\n{}\n".format(bases))

    locs = np.array([np.where(ndata[idx] == search_value[idx])[0] for idx in range(len(search_value))])
    print("LOCS:\n{}\n".format(locs))

    for idx in range(len(bases)):
        bases[idx][locs[idx]] = 0
    print("UPDATED BASES:\n{}\n".format(bases))

    res_idx = np.where(np.sum(bases, axis=0) == 0)[0]
    print("RES COLUMN:\n{}\n".format(res_idx))

    if len(res_idx) == 0:
        raise ValueError("match could not be found")

    res_val = np.array([ndata[idx][res_idx] for idx in range(len(ndata))])
    print("VALUES FROM COL-INDICES\n{}\n".format(res_val))

core_algorithm(data, search_value=(3, 30, 23)) # works successfully
# core_algorithm(data, search_value=(3, 30, 24)) # throws an error
```

One alternative method I have yet to explore is using set intersection/unions to find the same indices, though I'm not sure if that would necessarily improve performance. I posted a [similar example some time ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182648/finding-where-column-slices-of-elements-in-multi-dimensional-array-are-equal), though I later realized the code had bugs and could have been improved upon as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Python is not Java

Not everything needs to be in a `class`

```
class MaskOps():

    @staticmethod
    def get_base(shape, value, dtype=int):
        """ This function produces a base-mask, the values of which may be overwritten. """
        if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            res = np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype) * value
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            res = np.array([value for idx in range(np.prod(shape))]).reshape(shape)
        return res

    @staticmethod
    def alternate_base(shape, key):
        """ This function creates base-masks that consist of one of two value; the value depends on the index input as the parameter key. """
        if key % 2 == 0:
            value = 0.25
        else:
            value = 0.5
        return MaskOps().get_base(shape, value, dtype=float)

MO = MaskOps()
```

can just be

```
def get_base(..):
    ...
def alternate_base(...):
    ...
```

## looping

Python has a lot of elegant looping constructs

```
for idx in range(len(bases)):
    bases[idx][locs[idx]] = 0
```

for example is not one of them. This can be done with `zip`

```
for base, loc in zip(bases, locs):
     base[loc] = 0
```

Check out [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8g9scXeAcI) ([slides](https://archive.org/stream/pycon-2017-looping/looping#page/n49/mode/2up)) for tips on `enumerate`, `zip`, `generators` etc.

## return values, don't print them

When you print the value, it makes it harder to reuse this part of the code in another place. Better would be to split the `core_algorithm` in different functions all doing their part of the calculation, so you can test each of these parts individually, and decide how to print the result

## use `numpy`  (#1)

You have a lot of numpy arrays that you make from list comprehensions. It would be a lot easier and clearer to vectorize this, and use `numpy`'s large arsenal of native methods

```
def get_base(shape, value, dtype=int):
    """ This function produces a base-mask, the values of which may be overwritten. """
    if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
        res = np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype) * value
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        res = np.array([value for idx in range(np.prod(shape))]).reshape(shape)
    return res
```

can be more easily written as

```
def get_base(shape, value, dtype=int):
    dtypes = {int: int, float: float}
    if not dtype:
        dtype = dtypes.get(type(value), object)
    return np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype) * value
```

## use numpy (#2)

Instead of making this boolean mask yourself, why not just do:

```
mask = data == [[i] for i in search_value]
collapsed_mask = mask.all(axis=0)
result = data[:, collapsed_mask]
```

Comment: With regard to your first point, my intention was to make different classes to organize functions into logically consistent groups because my main code is very long. Is there a better way to organize such a code without using lots of globally defined functions?

With regard to your second point, I thought there might be a `numpy` way to do this instead of looping; your example was very helpful. Thanks for also providing a link for extra information. I was not aware boolean values could be used for indexing!

Comment: Also, my main code is actually slightly different. Where it says `locs = np.array([np.where(ndata[idx] == search_value[idx])[0] for idx in range(len(search_value))])`, specifically the part that reads `ndata[idx] == search_value[idx]`, my main code actually implements a custom condition inputter, so that one can specify `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, nearest-neighbor, etc. Is the `mask.all(axis=0)` approach adaptable in this way?

Comment: I've posted the updated question [in a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248227/how-to-optimize-a-mutli-dimensional-array-search-routine-one-condition-per-row) on stackoverflow.